# Typesetting a table to look like a spreadsheet

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, color

Continuing in my efforts to create particular computing environments in LaTeX, I'm now try to coerce a table to look like a spreadsheet.  It needs

- All columns other than the first having equal width (say 3cm)
- First row and column having a gray background
- First column and first row right aligned
- All other rows and columns left aligned

I can probably do this with a mess of stuff from the `array` and `colortbl` packages, but so far my efforts have been less than successful.  (If I get the alignment right, then the background doesn't fill the cell properly, for example).

Here's what I have so far, which is almost good, except for the formatting:

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|*{5}{>{\hfill}p{2cm}|}}
  \hline
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}&A&B&C&D&E\\
  \hline
  1&0&1&2&3&4\\
  \hline
  2&185&&&&\\
  \hline
  3&-31&&&&\\
  \hline
  4&-39&&&&\\
  \hline
  5&-367&&&&\\
  \hline
  6&-1159&&&&\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

The main difficulty seems to be formatting the first row differently from all other rows.  Is there a LaTeX environment which allows you to changing formatting mid-table?

Answer (score 9):

One possibility using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=3cm,align=left},
  text depth=0.5ex,
  text height=1.75ex,
  nodes in empty cells
},
row 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10,align=right}},
column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10,text width=1cm,align=right}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (mat) [table]
{
& 20  & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a possibility using `longtable`, `array` and `colortbl`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{gray!10}}R{1cm}*{5}{|L{3cm}}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}& \hfill20  & \hfill30 & \hfill40 & \hfill50 & \hfill60 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the last code I used `longtable` just in case a multi-page table is required (if this is not so, one can simply use `tabular`).

Comment: That's a great idea - I never would have thought of using TiKZ for typesetting matrices!

Comment: @Alasdair I've updated my answer with a TikZ-free option.

Comment: Very nice indeed.  However, I'm happy to use TiKZ - it's my preferred option for diagrams now.  Why do you need `longtable`?

Comment: @Alasdair longtable is just in case the table should span more than one page.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using "cals":

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{5mm}{20mm}{20mm}{20mm}{20mm}{20mm}}
\alignR
\brow
\def\bgcolor{gray!20}
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}
\cell{}\cell{A}\cell{B}\cell{C}\cell{D}\cell{E}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}\cell{1}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{0}\cell{1}\cell{2}\cell{3}\cell{4}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}\cell{2}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{185}
\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}\cell{3}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{-31}
\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}\cell{4}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{-39}
\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}\cell{5}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{-367}
\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{\bgcolor}\cell{6}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{-1159}
\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}\cell{}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```